# How to override save method for creation date of a particular field?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model:

```
class Agreement(models.Model):
    tos_agreed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_agreed = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       # Save original date when tos_agreed has been set to True
```

Initially the tos_agreed will be False, and when the user accepts I want to save the datetime of when the user has agreed to the tos.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the value of `tos_agreed` is True and set the `date_agreed` to `now()`:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.tos_agreed:
        self.date_agreed = datetime.now()
    super(Agreement, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The tos_agreed is False initially, so wouldn't `if self.tos_agreed` be False when saving for the first time? Wouldn't I have to check the args if tos_agreed is going to be true, then save the date?

Comment: Current answer code will result a problem on saving an exiting record since the agreed date would be resetted to each saving datetime.

To Solve i suggest to combine a check for date_agreed containing a value (not null)

Cheers;

Comment: @radev yes, I've left it as is intentionally, because this behavior could be desired, depends on the OP's use case. But thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a method that toggles the `tos_agreed` with something like `self.tos_agreed = True` and then saves the model, just add the `self.date_agreed = datetime.now()` before saving.